# Is there a command line shell and scripting interface for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Is there a command line shell and scripting interface for **WordPress** like **Drush** is for **Drupal**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't ever tried it, but it seems to cover the bases.  http://wp-cli.org/commands/

Comment: I can't find the command for backup but as you said it covers the bases. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use wordshell. For this you can visit http://wordshell.net

Comment: Thank you, but I will try the free WP-CLI as @Brian suggested.